# Ubuntu destop not working and Libreoffice menu text missing after ubuntu update

Tags: updates, libreoffice

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS smoothly and started forgetting MS-Windows. But recently I notice a upgrade notification of Ubuntu 12.10 in update Manager. I started upgrading. It took lot of time and after that machine re-booted and I got only a blue screen. I tried a lot to solve this problem but all of my effort was useless.

I uninstalled Ubuntu from windows Vista and then installed my original 12.04 again. Now, I just updated ubuntu instead of upgrade and then noticed my desktop icon are missing, right click not working on desktop and Libreoffice menus are not fully visible.

Comment: Please provide screenshot , just upload screenshot to imgur and provide link :)

Comment: likely https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1064962

Comment: @asis: this post seems to include more then one "question"

Answer (score 0):

Open up `dconf-editor` (you might have to install it beforehand) navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/background` and check that `show-desktop-icons` is checked.